# If a civilization lands on a new planet and comes into contact with native tribes, how would their language change over time?

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, civilization, language

So around 13,000 years ago, a group of refugees from a planet with Greco-Roman culture and technology were kicked off of their planet by what were essentially space vikings (space travel is done via magic instead of via technology in this universe so don't worry about that). Anyway, after a hundred years of traveling the cosmos, they wound up on this planet called Aurea. With a Mediterranean climate similar to their home planet and an extreme richness in precious metals, the Guants (what the refugees were called) decided to stay. However, the planet was very different from their homeworld in other ways.

Some areas of the planet were also home to native tribes. The far west was home to the Zebru Kingdom (essentially a more urbanized Zulu Kingdom). The far east was home to the Tengol Tribes (several constantly warring Mongol-esque tribes that constantly fought with each other and are expert horse, hippogriff, pegasus, and dakotaraptor riders).

Over time, the Guants formed their own kingdoms, one of which soon grew so powerful that it was able to completely unify the planet (including conquering the native populations) and form the Aurean Kingdom. Back when they lived on Olympia, Guant culture and technology resembled that of Byzantium during the time of the Macedonian Emperors.

Now, in the present, their culture is completely unrecognizable to the remaining Guant population on Olympia. While Guants on Olympia have largely stayed in touch with their old culture, the Aurean Kingdom has become something entirely different. Most importantly, the Aurean language is now completely incomprehensible to the Olympian Guants. While the Olympian Guants speak Byzantine Greek, the Aureans speak their own related language called Aurean (which incorporates many Zebru (isiZulu) and Tengol (Khalka Mongolian) loanwords and is a tonal language, as well as being extremely agglutinative).

Here is my question: Under what circumstances could these linguistic changes I have talked about be plausible? What would the relationship with the conquered tribes have to be? How much of Aurean would it be possible for the Olympian Guants to understand? What are some more differences that could arise from contact with these two languages for so long?

Comment: The breadth of this question makes it unanswerable. There are so many ways an environment affects a people living in it, they cannot be enumerated. And many are contradictory, depending upon local circumstances. Please reask your question focused on a specific “is this plausible” aspect of impact.

Comment: Far, far too broad! You've been around the block a few times, Weasel! Just remember: the SE model is *one focused question gets one direct & to the point answer*! VTC.

Comment: I can imagine half a dozen good solid questions coming out of this post.  Maybe start with linguistic drift and move on from there.

Comment: Much better!  I voted to reopen.  I'll keep my eye out for that to happen.  I love lingustics questions.  :-)

Comment: A friendly heads-up: at out current level of understanding of historical linguistics, 13 millennia is way longer than the time depth at which we can reconstruct the ancestry of languages. The Indo-European language family, which is the best studied and best understood family, can be reconstructed to maybe the beginning of the 3rd millennium BCE, about 5,000 years ago. Over a timespan of 13 millennia all traces of the original languages would have been lost and irrecoverable.

Comment: So basically, you just replaced local fauna and cultures with local language. The question is **too broad**! You can keep replacing one object another and same basic question appears. You really need to write a *focused question* where you home in on one specific phenomenon and ask a pointed query about that phenomenon. Keep closed.